# Align two elements on the same line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to align two different `<p>` elements on the same line. I got it to work but it completely messed up my logo.
The two `<p>` elements are the "TEST"s you see on either side of the logo.

The code for the alignment is this :
**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="logo" class="container">
<div align="center">        
    <img src="images/Logo.png" align="middle" alt="logo" height="105" width"105">
</div>
<div align="center">
 <p style="color:white;" id="countr">test</p> 
 <p style="color:white;" id="countl">test</p> 
</div>
    <h1 style="left:50px;"><span class="icon icon-size"></span><a href="#">Clubbed<span> In</span></a></h1>
<div align="center">
    <h2 class="motto" style="color : white">Connect. Communicate. Lead.</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#countr{display:inline-block;float:right;} 
#countl{display:inline-block;left:35px;float:left;}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Your markup is more complex than it needs to be.  Put all three elements in the same container, like so: `<div class="header"><div>TEST LEFT</div><div>LOGO HERE</div><div></div>TEST RIGHT</div></div>`, then apply some styling by making them each display: inline-block, with percentage (or fixed) widths, and this layout is simple to achieve.

Comment: I like your design :) but I think the blue color should be either darker or with lower Hue.

Comment: Is your issue only with aligning them on the sides? Seems like the code posted doesn't look like any of the other section in screenshot leaving the issue that you are mentioning about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VfcFr/)

```
<div>
  <p style="color:black;float:left;" id="countr">test</p> 
 <p style="color:black;float:right;" id="countl">test</p> 
</div>
    <h1 align="center" style="margin:0 auto;clear:both;"><span class="icon icon-size"></span><a href="#">Clubbed<span> In</span></a></h1>
<div align="center">
    <h2 class="motto" style="color : black">Connect. Communicate. Lead.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p>` are:

```
<p style="color:white;" id="countr">test</p> 
<p style="color:white;" id="countl">test</p>
```

Use this:

```
#countr, #countl {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

If doesn't work, then you can use this for `countr`

```
#countr {
float: left;
}
```

This will make them float inline!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would get rid of ALL of the div align="center"s from your HTML, just have every element without them. And then the float should work better. Even better, you might just want to position: absolute; each of the TEST texts